# Alert Dialog Icon Won't Set

Tags: java, android

I have a 14x14 png file (icon_alert.png) in my drawable-hdpi folder. This is how I am setting the icon:

```
alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_alert);
```

The icon is not there when the dialog is shown.

Answer (score 2):

You need a title too, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ExampleApp extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alt_bld.setMessage("Do you want to close this window ?")
.setCancelable(false)
.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
// Action for 'Yes' Button
}
})
.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
//  Action for 'NO' Button
dialog.cancel();
}
});
AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
// Title for AlertDialog
alert.setTitle("Title");
// Icon for AlertDialog
alert.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
alert.show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);`

The icon must be either `.png` or `.jpg`, I would highly recommend 16X16.